# Visit an element of a set within a set of sets as infrequently as possible

Tags: algorithms

I have a superset of sets `A...N`: `{ {A1,A2,...,Av}, {B1,B2,...,Bw}, ..., {N1,N2,...,Ny} }`.

The number of sets `A...N` within the superset is theoretically undetermined (in practice [100,300].)

The number of elements `v,w,x,...,y` within individual sets is theoretically undetermined (in practice about [10,60].)

The set of sets is already sorted in a sequence `S` in ascending order: 
`A1,A2,...,Av,B1,B2,...,Bw,...,N1,N2,...,Ny`.

Furthermore is known:
(a) the total number of elements `n`;
(b) the number of elements `m` of the set having the most elements.

I want to visit each element of the ordered sequence `S` such, that 
(1) each element `1...n` is visited just once;
(2) elements of individual sets `A...N` are never visited consecutively;
(3) (detailled below)

From (1) and (2), it seems to be clear, that I need to visit the elements in a ring, using the prime which is larger than `n mod m`.

The catch:

(3) the sets `A...N` should be visited such, that individual sets are visited as rarely as possible, i.e., the ring should not select an element from sets, e.g.: `A, E, M, V, A` (<-- no! visit an element within `B...D` instead.)

I struggle with requirement (3), and cannot find papers about, probably because there are none...

Suggestions and hints are very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

My hunch would be that you should use the smallest number coprime with $n$ and $\ge m$.

You see, if it were near to $\frac{n}2$, it would visit a set, then jump to the second half of the superset, and then back near the original point. So I decided to take the other extreme.

**A little elaboration, I may have been too vague:**

OP talked about the ring, and I gathered that it means a series of constant-length jumps among the elements. That constant $j$ must be coprime with $n$, otherwise the jumps would reach the starting point without visiting some elements. And if $j<m$, at some point the largest set would be visited twice consecutively.

For simplified example, take sets with lengths 10, 12, 14 and 24. $n=60$, $m=24$.

Numbers 24-28 all have common factors with 60. 29 is coprime with 60, so we can use that as $j$.

For the more complicated application that OP had in mind, this evens out much better. This particular example went near the $\frac{n}2$ I warned about.